# Getting error when trying to fetch data into a column from sequence using a trigger

Tags: triggers

```
`CREATE SEQUENCE HELLO_SEQ;
 SELECT HELLO_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL; 
--Created the below trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "HELLO_TRIG"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "WKSP_SANDBOX"."HELLO" EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  SELECT HELLO_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO   :"WKSP_SANDBOX"."HELLO"."CODE_ID"  FROM  dual;
END;`
```

*** Getting the below errors:
PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]
Error at line 2: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error at line 3: PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [0], [0], [], [], [], [], []

I was trying to create a sequence as shown above and called in a trigger. It was throwing the above mentioned errors.
Trying this under a schema : WKSP_SANDBOX
the table is HELLO
Main motto here is to auto populate value for the column "code_id" in the table "HELLO"